# Running batch file & commands from c# Forms application

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have the following code:

```
        private void RunBatchFile()
        {
            string batchFile = "FlashDevice.bat";
            string CurrentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string logFile = "\""+ CurrentDir + "\\logFile.txt\" 2>&1 ";
            string[] lines =
            {
                "cd \"c:\\Users\\thebi\\esp\\esp-idf\" ",
               // " \"c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe\" /k " +
                "\"c:\\Users\\thebi\\esp\\.espressif\\idf_cmd_init.bat\" \"c:\\Users\\thebi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\\" \"c:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\\"  > " + logFile,
                "cd " + projPath,
                "idf.py flash -b 921600 >> " + logFile
        };
            File.WriteAllLines(batchFile, lines);

            Process proc = null;
            try
            {
                string batDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batDir;
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c /wait " + batchFile;

                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();

               // proc.Start();
               // proc.WaitForExit();
                MessageBox.Show("Bat file executed !!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }


           // File.Delete(batchFile);
        }
```

It runs through the first few commands fine, but seems to skip the last one. If I open a blank command promt and copy the commands in one at a time from the file I created (FlashDevice.bat) it all works fine. But when I run it from the c# program, it just seems to completely ignore the crucial command.

I also tried :

```
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = batchFile;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k /wait ";
```

No difference. Could a more experienced c# person help point out the mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for what it's worth, this seems to work perfectly, without nearly as much messing around:

```
    private void ProgramFirmware()
    {
        string CurrentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string logFile = "\"" + CurrentDir + "\\logFile.txt\" 2>&1 ";

        string strCmdText =
            "'/c cd \"c:\\Users\\thebi\\esp\\esp-idf\" && " +
            " echo \"Setting Up environment...\" && " +
            "\"c:\\Users\\thebi\\esp\\.espressif\\idf_cmd_init.bat\" \"c:\\Users\\thebi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\\" \"c:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\\" > " + logFile + " && " +
            "cd " + projPath + "&& " +
            " echo \"Burning Device Firmware...\" && " +
            "idf.py flash -b 921600 >> " + logFile + "'";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
    }
```